# Cmpiler error in sqlcmd but no error in sql live

Tags: sql, oracle, compiler-errors, procedure, sqlcmd

[image]I have procedure on live sql, and it is created and executed successfully, but when I created it and executed it on sqlcmd I receive an compile error, please to advise..

Below is the procedure:

```
create or replace procedure p_get_num_for_max_salary(v_salary_out out integer, v_num_out out integer) as
v_RNO   integer;
v_SALARY    integer;
v_SALARY1   integer;
v_OVERTIME  integer;
v_REWARD    integer;
v_ACHIEVEMENTS  integer;
v_TOTAL integer;
v_PERCENTAGE  integer;
v_count  integer;
begin


execute immediate 'truncate  table salaries';
select count(*) into v_count from temp_salary;


for i in 1..v_count loop

select max(salary) into v_salary1 from temp_salary;

select RNO, SALARY, OVERTIME,   REWARD, ACHIEVEMENTS,   TOTAL,  PERCENTAGE 
into v_RNO, v_SALARY,   v_OVERTIME, v_REWARD,   v_ACHIEVEMENTS, v_TOTAL, v_PERCENTAGE 
from temp_salary where salary = v_salary1;

insert into salaries( rno, salary , overtime ,reward, achievements, total, PERCENTAGE ) 
values (v_RNO,  v_SALARY,   v_OVERTIME, v_REWARD,   v_ACHIEVEMENTS, v_TOTAL, v_PERCENTAGE);

commit;

delete from temp_salary where rno = v_rno and salary = v_salary and overtime = v_overtime and reward = v_reward and achievements = v_achievements;

commit;
end loop;

select max(salary) into v_salary_out from salaries;
select RNO into v_num_out from salaries where salary = v_salary_out and rownum = 1;
end;
```

Comment: What error you it's causing in sqlcmd?

Comment: That's not an error.  Tell us the error number, the error message, the error stack, the line number if it's a compiler error, the error stack if it's a runtime error, etc.

Comment: I edited the post and added the photo

Comment: It's always preferrable to post code and errors as text rather than images-- much more readable that way among other things.  You get compilation errors when creating the procedure.  Either type `show errors` after that or query `user_errors` to get the list of syntax errors.

Comment: it seems you're using the SYSTEM user, which is not advisable, better create your own one and use it. Second, from the screen shot, it seems the procedure creation is throwing an error, which we don't see, follow the previous comment by Justin to see what is wrong with it.